# Checking and Unchecking Checkboxes in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox

I have a form in MS Access with multiple checkboxes which I want to use to fill up one textbox.  If one of the checkboxes gets unchecked, I want its value to be deleted from the textbox without deleting other values. I'm new at using Access and coding in VBA (been reading ebooks for the past 3 weeks) and although I've tried to do research online it's been difficult for me to find the right code.

This is what I have so far:

---

### ***First code found***

```
Private Sub cb_click()
If Me.cb1 = True Then
Me.txtComentarios.Value = "INACTIVO;"
Else
Me.txtComentarios.Value = Null
End If

End Sub
```

---

### ***Second code found***

```
Private Sub cb2_Click()
If Me.cb2 = -1 Then
Me.[txtComentarios] = [txtComentarios] & "DISCREPANCIA"
Else
Me.[txtComentarios] = ""
End If
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Also I would like for the checkboxes to fill the textbox in the same order the chechboxes are displayed.

Ex.

cb1; cb2; cb3

If, cb2 gets unchecked and its value gets deleted, I should have "cb1; cb3" but if I re-check cb2 I should get "cb1; cb2; cb3" again.

I just hope someone could guide me in.  Thank you in advance.

Luz

Comment: Hi Cindy.  At work one of my tasks is to make a data entry of the errors some eployees make while evaluating and processing applications.  For example, one of the common errors is “Document Validation” which covers up a bunch of details (incomplete applications, expired documents, ilegible documents, discrepancies between applications and evidences included, etc).  Since an employee can incurr in multiple of these details I want to have all the specifics on one textbox (without having to type in all of that).  Also, I want for the specifics to be uniform.  =)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need events for each checkbox. Just create one procedure, which creates full text depending on checkboxes state and puts this text to the textbox. To call this function after each click on checkbox set `After Update` property of all checkboxes to `=MyFunctionToUpdateTextbox` instead of `[Event Procedure]`

```
Private Function MyFunctionToUpdateTextbox()
    Dim strText As String

    If Me.cb1 = True Then
        strText = strText & "INACTIVO;"
    End If
    If Me.cb2 = True Then
        strText = strText & "DISCREPANCIA;"
    End If
    If Me.cb3 = True Then
        strText = strText & "Text for cb3"
    End If

    Me.txtComentarios = strText
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, thank you for your help.  I tried using the code you provided but the first line “Private Function MyFunctionToUpdate Textbox()” turns red when I hit Enter to continue writing the code.  I’m not sure if I have to replace anything from that line to something that points out to the textbox where I want the info displayed or add something to that line.  I’m really lost on this coding part, I’m on grounds I’ve never been before.  Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: The name of the function should not contain spaces. I see you inserted a space before Textbox. For function use a shorter name, I named it just as an example. And this function should be added to form's module, not to standard one.

Comment: Yeah, simpler name: `Private Function UpdateComment()`.